# Identifying these Pink and White Flowers

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

I photographed this flowering shrub in Minnesota last summer. It had pink to white flowers with 5 petals in many clusters and serrated leaves:

[image: Large View]
[image: Detail]

I've tried to identify it myself, but so far none of my searches have given me enough to go off of. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [Spiraea](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pink%20Spirea&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsla2lg7zOAhUmBMAKHeOxDr8Q_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=921) shrub. Here is a general article on the genus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiraea.

There are 10s of species and probably hundreds of cultivars. One of the most common garden Spiraeas is [S. japonica](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=x320).

[image]
[image]